# Clang huge compilation?

Tags: linux, compilation, clang

Good Morning.

I am compiling Clang, following the instructions here [Getting Started: Building and Running Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html#build)

I am on linux and the compilation goes smoothly. But I think I am missing out something...

I want to compile ONLY clang, not all the related libraries. The option `-DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang` seems doing what I want (check `LLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS` [here](https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html))
If I use the instructions written there, I can compile, but I think I am compiling too much....a `build` directory of 70GB seems too much to me...

I tried to download the official debian source and compile the debian package (same source code! just using the "debian way" to create a package from official debian source), just to compare...The compilation goes smoothly, is very fast, and the `build` directory is much much smaller...as I expected...

I noticed in the [first link](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html#build) I provided the phrase "This builds both LLVM and Clang for debug mode."...

So, anyone knows if my problem is due to the fact that I am compiling a "debug mode" version? if so, how could I compile the default version? and is there a way to compile ONLY clang without LLVM?

Comment: Yes, debug mode binaries are typically much larger than release mode binaries. Try adding `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release"` flag to your cmake run.

Comment: Good point....digging in the CMakeLists seems that `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug"` was the default...I am trying it, I will tell you...

Comment: seems working...only 1.7GB now...would you like to make an answer, so I will accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, debug mode binaries are typically much larger than release mode binaries.

Cmake normally uses `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` to determine he build type. It can be set from the command line with `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release"` o `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug"` (sometimes there are other build types as well).